# how to draw an ammeter in physics lab?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need help drawing a physics device as in the picture.

[image: ammeter]

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Please show the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \draw (120:4) arc(120:60:4);
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(\Y/2)}] in {120,114,...,60}
 {\ifodd\Y
   \draw[rotate=\X] (4,0) -- (4.2,0);
  \else
  \draw[rotate=\X] (3.8,0) -- (4.3,0) node[pos=1.5,rotate=\X-90]{\Y}
  node[pos=-0.5,rotate=\X-90]{\Z}; 
 \fi}
 \draw[fill,thick] (0,0) circle (1pt) -- (74:4.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought of you right away: LOL. I thought of the famous phrase of superman at least in Italian films: "this is a job for superman". I recommend for future animation not to reverse the sign of the current otherwise it goes back and goes to 0 :-)